# Using where clause in monogdb's aggregate and pipeline

Tags: php, mongodb

Iam grouping a field, now I want to add where clause.
How to add where clause in following?

```
$query=array(
    'aggregate'=>$this->table_name,
    'pipeline'=> array(
        array('$group'=> array('_id'=> array(
                    'name'=>'$name',
                    "{$field}"=>'$'.$field
                ))),
        array('$group'=> array(
                '_id'=>'$_id.'.$field,
                'count'=> array('$sum'=>1)
            ))
    )
);
$result=$mongo_db->command($query);
```

Comment: The documentation is freely available and even asking google would have been faster.

Comment: I had done that, Did not find answer hence posted here.

Comment: Yet the accepted answer is what is available in the documentation you should have been reading. And from a google search of the terms https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+aggregate the reference page is listed right under the **top result**

Comment: Yes it is there, but at the same time it does not clearly mentions that match performs where condition. I do not have expertise in mongo, and its functions are very different from SQL. Hence It takes time to understand the Docs until a clear Example is provided. @quartaela gave an hint that it can be done by $match hence I was able to do it.

Comment: This link is two clicks away in an obvious path from the results displayed from the google search you were just given. It lists **all** the operators and if you are working with aggregation then you should have searched for that http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ You were downvoted **because** you clearly did no research. That is what is being explained to you. Please understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use $match operator while using aggregation

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/